# how to sent Information from ComboBox to Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml

I have a simple code nothing crazy but i just can't figure out how i can sent information from `ComboBox` to `Python`. I know the connection between pyton and qml is good, becouse i can sent other strings to python from qml.

Thanks in advance

Funcy.py

```
@pyqtSlot(str)
def mail(self, dropdown):

    print(dropdown) #should print Yes or No
```

Gui.qml

```
ComboBox
{
    id: dropdown

    // those are the options a user could choose
    model: ["No", "Yes"]
}

Button
{
    // some styling

    onClicked
    {
        backend.mail(dropdown.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the selected text from the ComboBox when the Button is pressed then you must send the currentText:

```cpp
onClicked: backend.mail(dropdown.currentText)
```

Comment: Thank you verry much that was the sulution!